# Ubuntu 16.04 does not load GUI after I log in

Tags: 16.04

After I log in the screen just remains the same. The login dialog disappears but the desktop is not loaded. The screen is empty. It was working fine till now. All of a sudden when I restarted this happened.

Comment: Are you able to login into TTY? Press Crl+alt+F1 (Ctrl+alt+F7 to go back)